# Can you disable autoloading for a specific PowerShell module?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to disable autoloading for a single PowerShell module? My initial research shows there is the `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` variable but we don't want to disable autoloading for all modules, just a specific in-house one we have written.

Comment: I think the only way would be to remove it from any of the directories in the `$env:PSModulePath` variable.

Comment: Yeah, we're doing that today but we wanted to simplify the process for our operational modules. We have to do this as the powers that be are worried that deploying our modules to a standard path might break something another team uses, but disabling autoloading for our operational modules would satisfy this concern.

Comment: It's really extreme, but you could use a dummy copy of the module as the latest version and deploy two versions of the module. The commands would autoload from the latest version, but you could make sure they do nothing. Then you have the pain of loading a specified version when you do want to use them. I don't think there is any great answers to this.

Comment: If there's really not a way to even create a module that disables autoloading for itself this seems like a missed opportunity for PowerShell. Autoloading is handy but in some cases granular control over what modules you use becomes important.

Comment: Yeah, the only option they offer is [ModuleQualified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#psmoduleautoloadingpreference)  which potentially changes the way you all work.

Comment: Yeah. I know about qualified module names but most others at the company I work for have no idea this is a thing. I've never tried it myself and wonder if it would break use of internal cmdlets in existing code since technically those are also modules.

Comment: Maybe worth asking for it as a feature request. Perhaps they could add it as property in the psd1 file.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12545), and this is actually not outside of my skill level to implement.

Comment: Just in case you don't know. That will only make it as a feature in to PowerShell Core. You could ask over at [their uservoice page](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) too, but I am not even sure if they are adding new features now to the Desktop version.

Comment: I'm aware. We won't be standardized on PS 5.1 forever, we're in the process of getting powershell core approved as a standard installation.